# Function overloading for minimze repetitive pattern

Tags: haskell

To learn haskell I've been building an framework much like Python Pandas.

In this scenario, I've defined a data called Series

```
    data Series
  = SInt [Int] ByteString
  | SFloat [Float] ByteString
  | SByteString [ByteString] ByteString
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

But due Haskell type system and my knowledge, I program simple functions like a Scalar Sum with this very repetitive coding pattern

```
sScalarSum :: Series -> Either Int Float
sScalarSum (SInt i _) = Left $ Data.List.sum i
sScalarSum (SFloat i _) = Right $ Data.List.sum i
sScalarSum (SByteString _ _) =
  error "Cannot sum strings. use applyDType to convert series to float or int"
```

Is there any form of overloading to minimize this code?

Can't I just do something like this?

```
sScalarSum :: Series -> Either Int Float
sScalarSum (Series i _) = Left $ Data.List.sum i
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to encode this information at the constructor level. Define a `Series` to be a parameterized list of *anything*

```
data Series a = Series [a] ByteString
```

but limit `sScalarSum` to summable types.

```
sScalarSum :: Num a => Series a -> a
sScalarSum (Series values _) = Data.List.sum values
```

More generally, you can define a `Foldable` instance for `Series` and use `sum` directly on your value.

```
instance Foldable Series where
    foldMap f (Series values _) = foldMap f values

sScalarSum :: Num a => Series a -> a
sScalarSum = Data.List.sum
```

Comment: This approach works for this. But when I need to have runtime different types in the "a" of Series [a] I run into problems. Like if an user dataset is Series [[String], [Int]] instead of [[Int], [Int]]. There is anyway to do this generically?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Neither `[[String], [Int]]` nor `[[Int], [Int]]` is a valid type.